# Django test logs Bad or Unauthorized requests

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I recently upgraded from django 1.11 to django 3.0.

Currently, when i launch `python manage.py test`, django logs any bad or unauthorized requests from my tests, the fact is : it did not log such while on 1.11

Exemple :

```sh
.2021-01-06 18:04:20,374 Unauthorized: /api/image/create
..2021-01-06 18:04:20,426 Bad Request: /api/image/transfer/create
.2021-01-06 18:04:20,436 Bad Request: /api/image/transfer/create

...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.008s

OK
Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
```

Did i miss something while reading django changelog ?

I'd like some light because i do not want to make a distribution without knowing if it's only warning or real error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since django `2.1`, they added logging to error 4xx and 5xx :

https://github.com/django/django/commit/10b44e45256ddda4258ae032b8d4725a3e3284e6

Just do before launching test :

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django.request')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

or create a decorator for each test you want to silence.